# Debugging a Sorting Algorithm in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, debugging, grouping

I'm learning to code and just finished writing a method that would **sort strings into subsets of anagrams** and return an array containing these subsets as subarrays. The original writing of the strings should be preserved.

My code passed the test provided by the bootcamp, but further testing revealed a **glitch**: in certain combinations a value that would shift to last position would then not be added to the respective subarray.

I've retraced the logic of my code several times but am failing to see why this is the case.

I'm looking to **understand where the glitch is coming from** in my method, so, if you can help me learn, please do! Thanks in advance! :)

[Here's the **glitch as screenshot** (values: 'creams', 'SCREAM', 'scream')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1V2z.png)

And the code itself:

```
test = ['cars', 'for', 'POTATOES', 'racs', 'four', 'scar', 'creams', 'SCREAM', 'scream']

# separate method for sorting
def sorted(word)
  word.downcase.chars.sort.join
end

def group_anagrams(words)
  result = []
  while words.length.positive?
    # use the first word as reference
    reference = [words.shift]
    # loop through the array looking for a match
    words.each do |word|
      # if match is found, add it to reference array and delete it from words
      reference << words.delete(word) if sorted(reference[0]) == sorted(word)
    end
    # when done, add reference array to result
    result << reference
  end
  result
end

p group_anagrams(test)
```

Comment: Would you mind copying and pasting the code into your question instead of linking an image? That allows people you want to help you to easily run and debug the code on their computers.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - just added!

Comment: The more Ruby-like way to do that is as follows: `test.group_by { |word| word.downcase.each_char.sort }.values #=> [["cars", "racs", "scar"], ["for"], ["POTATOES"], ["four"], ["creams", "SCREAM", "scream"]]`. Note that `.values` is executed on the hash `{["a", "c", "r", "s"]=>["cars", "racs", "scar"], ["f", "o", "r"]=>["for"], ["a", "e", "o", "o", "p", "s", "t", "t"]=>["POTATOES"], ["f", "o", "r", "u"]=>["four"], ["a", "c", "e", "m", "r", "s"]=>["creams", "SCREAM", "scream"]}`. See [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)

Comment: This is a grouping problem, *not* a sorting problem.  You're not actually defining what order the words should go in or anything like that.

Comment: Among other things, you're clobbering *reference*. It's probably also more useful to think of an anagram as an array of characters than as sorted words. Additionally, `[].length.positive?` is an overly complex way of asking `[].any?` or checking `[].empty?`; IMHO you'd be better off using #each or #map to iterate through your array rather than modifying *words* directly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at the call to the delete function. You're iterating over the words array but inside the each block `words.delete` changes the length of the array. You shouldn't mutate the array while you're iterating over it.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the problem. I didn't consider this aspect and it explains the behavior 100% - why only the 3d potential element is not being added.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code failed because you were deleting elements from `words` while simultaneously iterating through that array.  Here's a slight modification of your code which works fine:

```
def group_anagrams(words)
  words = words.dup
  result = []
  while !words.empty?
    reference = [words.shift]
    words.each do |word|
      reference << word if sorted(reference[0]) == sorted(word)
    end
    words -= reference
    result << reference
  end
  result
end
```

However, please note that for a large list of words, your algorithm will be O(N²), and it is much more complicated than it needs to be, so I would not recommend using it in practice.

You can use a hash table to speed things up:

```rb
def group_anagrams2(words)
  hash = {}
  words.each do |word|
    (hash[word.downcase.chars.sort] ||= []) << word
  end
  hash.values
end
```

However, you don't even have to write all that code yourself.  You can just replace all of the code above with this:

```rb
grouped_words = words.group_by { |w| w.downcase.chars.sort }.values
```

Comment: Thanks! This totally explains it. I didn't consider that the length changes by deletion and the index the last element is on has technically been already iterated over.

Also a very useful edit - thanks for that too!

As to the rest: I'm very aware that no-one would ever iterate this way (at least I hope so, lol). That was never the point, it's an exercise in building a logical system and in the next round I'm gonna use a hash just like the  solution provided by the bootcamp suggests, but at first I just did what came naturally to my mind at this point - a very simple linear iteration.

Answer (score 0):

### An Alternative Solution

Others have already addressed some of the issues with your current code. Rather than addressing how to fix the existing code, I'm simply going to offer what I would consider a more idiomatic solution to the problem using iteration and a Hash to hold the relevant results for each word as an Array of matching anagrams. This was tested with Ruby 3.1.0, but should work with Ruby >= 2.7.3.

```rb
words = %w[cars for POTATOES racs four scar creams SCREAM scream]
words.map!(&:downcase).uniq!.sort!
#=> ["cars", "creams", "for", "four", "potatoes", "racs", "scar", "scream"]

matches = {}
words.map do |word|
  anagrams = word.chars.permutation.map &:join
  matches[word] =
    # reject the word itself but select all its anagrams
    words.reject { _1 == word }.select { anagrams.include? _1 }
end

# select only Hash elements with non-empty Array values
matches.select! { |_, values| values.any? }
```

This will return a Hash with each word in *words* as a key, with an Array of matching words that are anagrams of that key as the value. It excludes the key itself from the list of matching values, as well as any key/value pairs where no matches were found. The *matches* Hash now holds:

```rb
{"cars"=>["racs", "scar"],
 "creams"=>["scream"],
 "racs"=>["cars", "scar"],
 "scar"=>["cars", "racs"],
 "scream"=>["creams"]}
```

If you want to sort, group, or otherwise modify the results further you can, but this seems to meet the underlying objective you described in your original post.

Comment: Thanks for the best practice example! It is very useful in understanding the limitations of using mere arrays. As noted above - hash is gonna be my next take on the same task.